# Netbeans PHP single click open file in navigator

Tags: netbeans

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, although I'm using this site almost every day.

**Here's my question: *is there a way to open file from navigator in Netbeans with single click?***

I can't find option for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your application, you can just execute it (check the netbeans menu for more options) by pressing shift+F6 or ctrl+F6

you must configure your browser (Tools => Options) and probablly also put the correct URL settings when making a new project

---

icon on the toolbar:
right click on the IDE window => Customize => Drag the "Execute File" icon to your bar

i dont know if this is the exact word it appears on the menu, since im using netbeans in another language, but you can get the idea

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I'm working a lot, so single click will be the best solution like in **Zend Studio**.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help me, but even with icon I have two clicks, first to select file and second to execute command :)

Comment: you can make a autoit or autohotkey script then